# Comparing arrays in javascript error

Tags: javascript, json

I trying to compare 2 list of json values. If the comparison is true, do not display the display and display only values where the statement is false.

Here is the code:

```
var files= '{"files":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","title":"Armoogum","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc2.pdf"}]}';
  var result = '[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"},';

       for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                                   var file = files[i];                 
                      for(var j=0;j<arrayResults.length;j++){   

                          if (files[i]==arrayResults[j].json.name){
                              alert("Matching found");
                            //full_list =  full_list + arrayResults[j].json.name + " " + arrayResults[j]._id + "  " + arrayResults[j].json.title + " " + arrayResults[j].json.path + '<br />';

                          }else {

                            alert("no similar files");
                             str += '<br /><div class="fileSection">' + '<br/>' + '<input class="fileName" type="hidden" value="'+ file.name + '" />' + file.name + '<br/>' + '<input class="fileTitle" type="hidden" value="'+ file.title +'" />' +  file.title + '<br/>' + '<input class="filePath" type="hidden" value="'+ file.path +'" />' + '<button onclick="add(this)">Add</button> '+  '</div><br/>' ;

                          }                           


                   }
```

The output result should be only json list for doc2.pdf. Instead it is just displaying all the list.

i will highly appreciate if i can get some help.

Comment: Files isn't even an array, it's a string.

Comment: @cale_b unfortunately lodash will not help with conceptual confusion between JSON strings and JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to correct. Mainly you could use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to extract the data:

```js
var files= '{"files":[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"},{"name":"doc2.pdf","title":"Armoogum","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc2.pdf"}]}';
var result = '[{"name":"doc1.pdf","title":"networking","path":"mfpreader.comze.com\/files\/doc1.pdf"}]';

// you need to convert the above strings to arrays:
files = JSON.parse(files).files; // You need the files property
arrayResults = JSON.parse(result);

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    for(var j=0;j<arrayResults.length;j++){
        // note the name property on the files[i] object:
        if (files[i].name===arrayResults[j].name){ 
            alert("Matching found for " + files[i].name);
        }else {
            alert("no similar files for " + files[i].name);
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare something in  javascript ,you had better use the `===`without type conversion  instead of `==`.

see here:[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: And why would that make any difference here?

Comment: @torazaburo  I haven't test his code, just a suggest

Comment: Sounds like a comment then, not an answer.